# How to make the same component to act differently depending on the route

Tags: reactjs, architecture, react-router, redux-saga

I need a high level architecture advice. React, Redux, Redux-Saga is already in use.

Endpoints:

- /api/userData

just some data, ignore for now...

Then:

- `/api/canView returns [{...}]`
- `/api/canEdit returns [{...}]`
- `/api/mustEdit returns [{...}]`

...all three arrays are very similar and consist of (as an example):

`{age: 22, name: "John", country: "USA"}, {age: 30, name: "Jane", country: "USA"}`

These objects are merged into an object of arrays

`{ age: [22, 30], name: ["John", "Jane"], country: ["USA"]}`

So all the values are unique and filters are drawn as buttons for each value grouped by a key. Kind of a filter that is used to build a request for the data about those users from /userData.

I need two pages where:

- page A shows filters from `/canView`
- page B shows filters from either `/canEdit` or `/mustEdit` based on a toggle

Page layout/components are the same for both pages except page B has a toggle mentioned above.

Each page has a sub-route or a mode (string) that affects the request that we are sending towards /userData.

The tricky part is that when you are switching between the modes at page "A", you have to keep selected filters, while for page "B" you should always reset those.

***What I've tried:***

- Keep everything in a store

*The first approach looks messy and sometimes switching modes still renders old data while fetching, and I also have to reset everything on any route change via sagas.*

- Keep page related data locally at pages state

*The second approach, however, resets the local state on each route change while I need to keep selected filters.*

[basic visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFWX3.png)

When [22] is clicked at AGE section, I will find the object(s) where
`age: 22` and use it as a request data towards `/api/userData`

SubRoute such as `blabla` from `/A/blabla` should be added to the request too.

Again, when navigating between subroutes on PAGE A, I need to keep active filters active, but on PAGE B it should reset filters.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're referring to by filters in this context, could you post the code for one of these components?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington Thank you. I've added an image with a simplified design of an app.

Answer (score 0):

okay, 
Let's make it as simple as I can 
There is a feature called match that React Router provides us with, you need to pass it down to a component like props and it could give you access to whatever the pass you are on, and from here you can just do whatever logics you wanna do, you can find out more here: 
[match.params](https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params)
Hopefully, this will help

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand that the only difference between those routes is the route itself since the component is the same and I also aware that it is passed as a prop. But I still can not see the whole picture.

Comment: Have you been through the link I provided for you?
Try to write 
```    console.log(match.props);      ```
at your component share your console with me

Comment: Yes. I did that it has access to ```{path: "/home/regions", url: "/home/regions", isExact: true, params: {…}}```. 
I've tried ```withRouter()``` on the inner components.
I've tried to ```render={ props =>{}}``` to provide some additional data to components. There are many ways of getting the path. 
But then what? Have multiple different logics within the same component?